# How to reduce final docker image size containing numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, docker, scikit-learn, scipy

I have posted this question over at docker hub as well as I am not sure which community would have more of a response to my question.  I am new to creating docker images and have put together a Dockerfile that creates an image that works but the final image size is 600MB+ and would like somebody that is more advance than I to advise if there is anything I can do to reduce this.  I have read many blogs about various strategies to do so and have gone the Python virtual environment route.  I am really concerned about build times as I will not be building often but would like to see the final image size be a bit leaner than what it is.

What I am doing is building an image with a python application, fava which is a web gui front-end to the accounting program beancount.  These two python applications alone are easy enough and the fava team even provide a Dockerfile based on alpine to build a light image.  However, the issue I have is I want to extend this by including an extension to this python application (smart_importer) which provides some machine learning features that will automate aspects of the transaction importing process.  This extension depends on numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn and this is where the extra weight comes from. I originally tried to extended the alpine approach that the fava team had but installing scipy on alpine fails horribly which I cannot resolve.  Using python slim I can build a fairly small (<200mb) final image with just fava and beancount...but as I said this balloons with the introduction of the needed dependencies of smart_importer.

Here is the Dockerfile I have currently, are there any changes I can easily make to get the final image size down that I am not seeing?  Greatly appreciate any pointers one might have.

```
FROM python:slim AS base

FROM base as builder

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

#WORKDIR /install
COPY ./library-dependencies.txt /tmp/library-dependencies.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
#ENV PATH="/install:${PATH}"

RUN buildDeps='build-essential gcc gfortran python3-dev' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && cat /tmp/library-dependencies.txt | egrep -v "^\s*(#|$)" | xargs apt-get install -y \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && CFLAGS="-g0 -Wl,--strip-all -I/usr/include:/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib" \
        pip3 install \
#       --prefix="/install" \
        --no-cache-dir \
        --compile \
        --global-option=build_ext \
        --global-option="-j 6" \
        -r /tmp/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -r \
    /tmp/requirements.txt \
        /tmp/library-dependencies.txt

FROM base
COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv
COPY ./library-dependencies.txt /tmp/library-dependencies.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && cat /tmp/library-dependencies.txt | egrep -v "^\s*(#|$)" | xargs apt-get install -y \
    && apt-get install -y libgomp1 --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENV BEANCOUNT_FILE ""
ENV FAVA_OPTIONS ""
EXPOSE 5000
CMD fava --host 0.0.0.0 $FAVA_OPTIONS $BEANCOUNT_FILE
```

requirements.txt

```
# numeric packages needed for smart_importer
Cython==0.28.5
numpy==1.15.1
scipy==1.1.0
scikit-learn

#fava
fava
smart_importer
```

library-dependencies.txt

```
libopenblas-dev
liblapack-dev

libxml2-dev
libxslt1-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker run --rm imagename du -k /` or similar commands to see where space is getting taken up?

Comment: command posted by @DavidMaze is very useful, looking at the output from this command I was able to shave the size down to 421mb, almost half of that are python packages I have installed and need, another 60mb are packages outside of python and ~120mb is the rest.  I don't see much more I can cut without taking drastic steps.

Answer (score 0):

Does installing the py3-scipy package with apk work?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Python on Alpine Linux. Any Dockerfile changes you make are not going to get your image nearly as small as Alpine.

This looks like a good start: https://github.com/jfloff/alpine-python

Comment: Alpine is not a good base image, even if can result in slightly smaller images. Lack of binary wheels means much more compilation, so slower builds. Different libc will sometimes lead to subtle bugs. Longer version: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/

Comment: From that article: `Most of these problems have already been fixed`. Also, if installing packages takes too long for builds you can build a new base image and go from there - there's also multi-stage builds that can help. Not saying it's a moot point, but it's not a deal breaker, IMO

Comment: I have tried building on Alpine in the past and had major headaches getting scipy to install and eventually abandoned this route.  I agree the image size using Alpine can result in a smaller image but without the ability of getting needed packages to compile and install it's not an option.  I will give the image you linked a try though for completeness.  As stated I am not concerned about image build times and more interested in reducing final image size.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: tried the linked alpine based image and no luck building scipy using that as a base image.  Same issues I encountered when I first attempted to use Alpine as he base image.  The linked git also makes mention of projects that use this image as a base, including one that claimed to come with numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn installed along side other data scientist tools....this image fails to build for the same reasons.